# Bootstrap modal with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I want to get the output message when I click the button. It wants to be Successfully saved. How to create the modal.

```
<input type="submit" 
       class="btn btn-primary" 
       value="Remove From Verify" 
       ng-show="IsVerifyPage" 
       ng-click="save()">
```

#### JS File

```
$scope.save = function() {
   //connect with backend
}).success(function(data, status) {
     alert('Successfully Saved');
  })
  .error(function(error) {
     console.log($scope.status);
  });
}
```

Comment: see this https://github.com/matowens/ng-notify

Comment: Are you using `bootstrap` or `ui.bootstrap`?

Comment: Use SweetAlert : http://oitozero.github.io/ngSweetAlert/#/home for this type of messages.

Comment: ReferenceError: SweetAlert is not defined

Comment: you can use angular-ui-bootstrap library or show normal bootstrap alerts. Refer here for bootstrap alerts: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp

Comment: I asked like this.https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GjfVNXcFWm7Xag126t8B?p=preview see this

Answer (score 0):

My must inject to you controller SweetAlert. and then when you want to make this alert use like in my example.

```
NameYouController.$inject = ['$scope','SweetAlert'];
    function NameYouController( $scope, SweetAlert) {
        $scope.save = function() {
           //connect with backend
        }).success(function(data, status) {
          return SweetAlert.swal('Successfully Saved');
        }).error(function(error) {
          console.log($scope.status);
      });
    }
```